# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'components/app'. webpack + reactjs issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm newbie in webpack and react. hope you can help me.

I faced a problem and can't find any working solution in the internet.
When i trying to run webpack-dev-serverI geting "Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'components/app'" error all the time.

Here my files structure.

root/ webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://127.0.0.1:8080/',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
         query: {
             presets: ['es2015', 'react']
         }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ]
};
```

root/ .babelrc

```
{
    presets: ["react", "es2015"],
    plugins: ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

root/src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from 'components/app';

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

root/src/components/app.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default class App extends React.component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello There</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with **Robert Moskal** answer, use Relative path to import, at the same time if you really want the absolute path to work you may have to add one more line in your `webpack.config.js` inside your resolve section of it add this below line

```
root: path.resolve('./src'),
```

this  will help to resolve the root and you can easily import using absolute path from folders inside the src folder. I would show you my sample `webpack.config.js` below

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const loaders = require('./webpack/loaders');
const plugins = require('./webpack/plugins');

const applicationEntries = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true']
  : [];

const mainEntry = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  ? './src/sample/index.tsx'
  : './src/lib/index.tsx';

module.exports = {
  entry: [mainEntry].concat(applicationEntries),

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
  },

  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
    'source-map' :
    'inline-source-map',

  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve('./src'),
    extensions: [
      '',
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.tsx',
      '.ts',
      '.js',
      '.json',
    ],
  },

  plugins: plugins,

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: { index: '/' },
  },

  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      loaders.tslint,
    ],
    loaders: [
      loaders.tsx,
      loaders.html,
      loaders.css,
      loaders.scss,
      loaders.eot,
      loaders.svg,
      loaders.ttf,
      loaders.woff,
      loaders.json,
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: { mimetype: 'image/png' },
      },
    ],
  },

  externals: {
    'react/lib/ReactContext': 'window',
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
    'react/addons': true,
  },

};
```

Comment: Big thanks @KeshShan for your webpack.config.js example and root: path.resolve advice

Comment: @AntonArtemev no problem, glad that my answer helped you!! :)

Comment: Good answer, though if someone on a project submitted a pull request with a webpack hack like that I would direct that they simply follow the es6 module importing convention.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a relative path to app in your index.js file. So

```
import App from './components/app'
```

Without the relative path notation, the module import system looks in the node_modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [module aliasing](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias). The `resolve` section of your config should look something like:

```js
const path = require('path');

resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/')
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to the `paths` option in TypeScript config files.